# Sequencing of favorite vs ignored tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I have a favorite tag : **arduino-duemilanove**

This relates to the Arduino board the Duemilanove.

I have an ignored tag: **arduino-due**

These are totally different boards (devices), despite the superficial similarity of the names.

However I find that in the "Questions" list, the ignored tag overrides the favorite tag. That is, a question tagged with both tags is greyed out.

Surely, if I say that **arduino-duemilanove** is a favorite of mine, it should be highlighted as a favorite, not greyed out?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually doing both, but the ignorance background color almost defeats the favorite background color.

This is what happens if I have [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) in favorites and [people-reached](/questions/tagged/people-reached) in ignored.

> [image]

You see the faint blue color?

Comment: Ah yes, quite amusing. :) I thought someone might reply that they would answer "programming" questions but not "homework" and that thus the existing system is OK. Here's another suggestion: If a particular question is both "favorite" and "ignored" then the two cancel out, and leave the question at the default color. Or, come up with a third color scheme that indicates this favorite/ignored status. One that is a bit easier to spot. :P